# Swipe up cancels a refresh mode in the SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I use `SwipeRefershLayout` with `AppBarLayout` that can collapse. But if user scrolls up layout and after scrolls down then `SwipeRefreshLayout` enables a refresh mode although layout was not scrolled at the top. I fix this bug so:

```
appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int verticalOffset) {
       refreshLayout.setEnabled(verticalOffset == 0);
   }
});
```

And it works perfect! But I noticed now that user can hide `SwipeProgressBar` when he makes a **swipe up**. (When `SwipeRefreshLayout` shows this `SwipeProgressBar`, the refresh mode enabled).

How to fix it?

My xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/parallax"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/orange"
                    android:minHeight="250dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="28dp">

                    <!-- my header -->

                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```